# Copying every third cell across in a 1x13 range in one sheet and pasting onto a 5x1 range in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 worksheets Sheet1 and Sheet2.  Sheet1 has a range C12:O12 whilst Sheet2 has a range E4:E8.  I need to copy the first and every third cell in range C12:O12  and paste into range E4:E8.  Here is my code;

```
Sub PX() 'COPY DATA FROM ROW ONE SHEET INTO A COLUMN on another sheet
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E4:E8").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C12:O12").Offset(0, 3).Value)
End Sub
```

However, it just seems to transpose Range("C12:O12") and paste the range("C12:G12").  Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

3try this:

```
Sub main()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 5
    Sheet2.Cells(i + 3, 5) = Sheet1.Cells(12, (i - 1) * 3 + 3)
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Sub price()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 5
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 3, 5) =     Sheets("HistoricalDataRequest").Cells(12, i * 3)
    Next i
    End Sub      I have modified it as above its fine except that the third output is wrong....Can anyone see why??

Comment: @user3565577 please update your original question with the current code you're using. Describe in more detail what you think should be the result, the code posted above (and from your comment) yields identical results when I test it.